# Overwriting a scheduled task

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

How would one go about executing a task after x seconds unless otherwise overwritten by a new scheduled task?

The scenario is that I would like to execute a task 1 second after the user has finished typing in my JTextField. For that, I would need to schedule the task, and reschedule it every time the 'document' changes.

I tried using a `ScheduledExecutorService`, but scheduling just adds the task to a list, rather than cancelling the previous task.

Here's where I would like it to go:

```
class TextChangeListener implements DocumentListener {
    private final ??? updater = new ???();

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        // Wait for the user to finish typing first
        updater.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomeStuff();
            }
        }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were on track with your ScheduledExecutorService - you just need to hold on to the `Future` it returns.  Check out the [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method.  I'm assuming you are using the [`schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method.

So basically you'd want to do something like

```
if (future != null) {
    future.cancel();
}
future = // do scheduling code with ScheduledExecutorService
```